Incompatibility between <format> and <chrono> modules in G++13
I have a very simple project where I'm trying to learn how to use modules in C++20:
> tree
.
├── foo_something.cxx
└── main.cxx

1 directory, 2 files

main.cxx:
import <iostream>;
import foo.something;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hi\n";
}

foo_something.cxx:
export module foo.something;

import <format>;
import <chrono>; // This seems to cause the issue

int hi() {
    return 5;
}

And I'm building this with:
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header format -x c++-system-header chrono -x c++-system-header iostream
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c foo_something.cxx
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts main.cxx

On the last command though, I get this weird error:
> g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts main.cxx
‘
/usr/include/c++/13/format:2862: confused by earlier errors, bailing out

If I comment out the import <chrono> in foo_something.cxx, it builds and runs fine.
My questions are:

Is it expected than a completely unused module import can affect the compilation?
What specifically is going wrong?

In case it's relevant:
> g++ --version
g++ (SUSE Linux) 13.3.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



This is surely a compiler bug. It wouldn't be unexpected to still find bugs in modules implementations.

Your program is importing header units. Can you use named modules, instead? This article explains the difference: Compare header units, modules, and precompiled headers. It's from Microsoft Learn, but it should be a useful read no matter what compiler you are using. Perhaps best of all would be to use C++23's import std;. On MSVC, it compiles faster than importing individual header units, and, as a bonus, you don't have to fiddle with long lists of include files or import declarations.

Let me try with C++23 and import std;

One bit of advice: At this stage, import std; does always not play well with programs that also import header units or have include directives in the global module fragment.  If you have problems, try using import std; in all of your modules. The exception is C-language headers, such as #include <assert.h> and #include <errno.h>, which depend on macros. Those can safely be included in the global module fragment at the top of a module unit (use the .h versions). The global module fragment begins with the declaration module;, and precedes all other parts of a module file.

Mixing header units (like import <iostream>;) and named modules is still poorly supported. You can try this code under MSVC, it is (currently) the most advanced in this area
